# What's the best chrome extensions that shows the number of tabs for all open windows?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, counter

I tried several but they either show the number for the active window only or they don't calculate it correctly, or come with a lot of bloat.

Anyone knows a simple extension that only shows the count for all tabs in all windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Session buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en) has an option "Show tab count of current session on extension icon" for this.